# jdk.incubator.httpclient URI query string is truncated when containing an encoded reserved character

Tags: http, character-encoding, uri, java-9

Example URI string parsed by `new URI(string)` that contains an encoded reserved character "#" (%23) in the query string:

`http://localhost:34455/ldp-test-43272e5c-1e3f-4bb8-8541-fa5ea6d6567a?predicate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Foa%23hasBody`

The URI object is then simply passed to `HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri)`

Here is the log, the first entry shows that the server processed request string is truncated, yet the response and request URIs show the complete string:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2018:10:30:51 +0000] "GET /ldp-test-43272e5c-
1e3f-4bb8-8541-fa5ea6d6567a?predicate=http://www.w3.org/ns/oa 
HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "-" "-" 64

INFO  [2018-02-22 10:30:51,137] cool.pandora.ldpclient.LdpClientImpl: 
request URI is http://localhost:34455/ldp-test-43272e5c-1e3f-4bb8-
8541-fa5ea6d6567a?
predicate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Foa%23hasBody

INFO  [2018-02-22 10:30:51,141] cool.pandora.ldpclient.LdpClientImpl: 
response URI is http://localhost:34455/ldp-test-43272e5c-1e3f-4bb8-
8541-fa5ea6d6567a?
predicate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Foa%23hasBody

INFO  [2018-02-22 10:30:51,141] cool.pandora.ldpclient.LdpClientImpl: 
http version is HTTP_1_1

INFO  [2018-02-22 10:30:51,141] cool.pandora.ldpclient.LdpClientImpl: 
status code is 200

INFO  [2018-02-22 10:30:51,141] cool.pandora.ldpclient.LdpClientImpl: 
final request URI is http://localhost:34455/ldp-test-43272e5c-1e3f-
4bb8-8541-fa5ea6d6567a?
predicate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Foa%23hasBody

INFO  [2018-02-22 10:30:51,141] cool.pandora.ldpclient.LdpClientImpl: 
Content Length is[3]
```

this seems to be **a bug** in the [jdk.incubator.http](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/package-summary.html) and not in URI.

It is not clear to me in the Exchange if additional URI string building or construction occurs, but if the query string is decoded somewhere without reencoding it would be my first guess as the suspect.

Perhaps someone can independently verify this?

Also, I believe that it is not the server implementation because the same request URI (on a non-test instance) with `curl` works.

```
172.18.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2018:09:22:31 +0000] "GET /test10?
predicate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Foa%23hasBody HTTP/1.1" 200 
795 "-" "curl/7.55.1" 35
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this issue. It is indeed a bug in the JDK HTTP Client code. The following JIRA has been filed to track it:
  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198716